The following _TypeError was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: ObxState#2f6f5): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
**LoginController**

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:akin/api/api_services.dart';
import 'package:akin/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:akin/view/screens/dashboard_bottom_navigation_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_rx/get_rx.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class LoginController extends GetxController{

  Rx<bool> loading = false.obs;

  var userList = {}.obs;

  final emailController = TextEditingController().obs;
  final passwordController = TextEditingController().obs;

  Future<UserModel> loginAPI() async {


    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "email" : emailController.value.text,
      "password" : passwordController.value.text
    };

    var dataEncode = jsonEncode(body);

    string url = "API endpoint";

    final response = await post(Uri.parse("url"),
        body: dataEncode
    );

    var loginData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if(loginData['status']==200){
      Get.snackbar(loginData['msg'],"Thank You");
      Get.off(()=> DashboardBottomNavigationScreen());
      userList.value = loginData['data'];
      // print(userList);
      //return userModelFromJson(response.body);

    }else{
      Get.snackbar(loginData['msg'],"Invalids Credential");
    }
    throw{
      Get.snackbar("Error", "APi error")

    };

  }

}


**HomeScreen**


// Outside the build method 
final controller = Get.put(LoginController());

body : Container(
            width: wi*1,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: he*0.01,),
                Container(
                  height: he*0.06,
                  width: wi*1,
                  color: lightBlue,
                  child: Obx(() {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text("Welcome "+controller.userList['first_name'],style: TextStyle(
                          color: white,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontFamily: "Roboto"
                      ),),
                    );
                  }
                  ),
                );


**Json **

{
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "Logged in successfully",
    "data": {
        "id": 70,
        "salutation_id": 1,
        "countrycode_id": 77,
        "first_name": "****",
        "last_name": "****",
        "mobile": "0000000000",
        "email": "demo@gmail.com",
        "password": "123456789",
        "user_type": 3,
        "department_permission": null,
        "created_date": "2024-07-08",
        "created_time": "01:16:30 PM",
        "updated_date": null,
        "updated_time": null,
        "status": 1,
        "del_status": 1,
        "token": "5626748485989555134f4e8b484cda72"
    }
}

The issue I'm facing is that the output shows "your user list is null," and there are specific details that I want to display on the screen. The controller keeps getting initialized repeatedly, resulting in it returning null values.i think i am not injecting the GetxController dependencies where to use put() and find<>
Could someone please explain the logic behind the GetxController?
every thing that i could do

I would suggest you to use get_cli. https://medium.com/@yurinovicow/flutter-getx-new-project-with-get-cli-a3bae832868f
it will create a proper folder structure and instantiate your controllers in the right place and time.


Put controller in build method.

Incorrect usage of Obx(). Use Obx on exact widget with .obs var.
In your case - Center(child: Obx(() => Text(...

Use String interpolation.
"Welcome "+controller.userList['first_name'], -> 'Welcome ${controller.userList['first_name']}',


String interpolation implicitly use toString() method on object.
